# Why a "*" in Lua's file:read("*a")?

Tags: lua

Here is a code chunk to read the contents of a file at the given `path` which seems widely used

```
local file = open(path, "r")
local content = file:read("*a")
file:close()
```

People say that `"*a"` allows to read the whole file but I find no mention of it in the 5.4 reference manual contrary to the `"a"` format specifier.

What is the meaning of the `*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asterisk was used in formats in versions before 5.3 (e.g. [4.0](https://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#read) or [5.2](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-file:read)).

Currently it's supported for the sake of compatibility: [g_read](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/liolib.c.html#g_read). Formats with and without `*` are equivalent.

Comment: Asterisk was removed in 5.3

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, That's correct; fixed it. When writing the answer I verified with 5.0 refman, and I suppose the asterisk blurred together with quotation mark. I should increase frequency of breaks from computer screen.